# Getting actual timestemp OS independent

Tags: javascript, time

Ok, guys, my problem is simple I need a  pop on my website to be shown at certain times and I don't want the user to be able to change time on OS thus tricking the popup and one last thing I would prefer not to query my server for the timestamp. Is there some global API for such thing something like GET currenttimestamp.org?

Comment: Why would you prefer querying someone else's server instead of your own, then?

Comment: Note that if you're doing this purely through JS on the client (including making a request to whatever service to get hold of the time), anyone can inspect and see what's going on and possibly make it pop up manually.  To truly make it so they can't see it at the wrong time, you need to not serve it from your server in the first place.

Comment: There is always a way to "trick" the client if you have an understanding of what the code is doing. The real question is what is it you are actually trying to accomplish with the popup? Perhaps there is a way to achieve your goal either without the popup or some other way.

Comment: When serving the page, calculate `(futureTimestamp-now)` and put that value into the page. Then your js can use that to count down. No need for any further requests.

Answer (score 1):

you could you the site https://worldtimeapi.org/ to get the current time (timestamp or other formats).

You could get it for the current IP

```
https://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip
```

Or for a specific timezone.

```
https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/London
```

Check out the documentation for more alternatives: https://worldtimeapi.org/api